# Order for specifying type for <script>

Tags: html, css, performance

A very quick question - does it matter at all for the optimal performance whether the type of the script is specified before or after the source path?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myjavascript.js"></script>
```

vs

```
<script src="/myjavascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Similarly, would it matter if ***rel="stylesheet"*** and ***type="text/css"*** are specified before or after ***href*** for css files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser that reads your HTML code will read *all* the attributes before processing your object. Thus the order should not matter.

However, ordering the attributes in a certain way may help you making modifications to the code faster, this is how I usually order them :

1. class
2. id, name
3. data-*
4. src, for, type, href, value
5. title, alt
6. role, aria-*

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't matter which comes first and which comes last. what matters is that the src attribute links to the correct location of the script source.

for formality (and because i grew with it) i always add a type = "text/javascript":

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{link-to-js-file}"></script>
```

but as far as HTML5 is concerned, you are no longer required to put "type='text/javascript'" beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter.

But for HTML5, we don't require to specify type="text/javascript"